# Update each column's value pertaining to a specific row number? sqlite sqlite3

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite, sql-update

I and terrible with databases and sql, but know the basics and this is a bit beyond basics I believe. I need a way to update a an entire rows values, where the row is selected by row number, because I have no guarantee of a value pertaining to any of the columns in that row.

Example DB Table:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
a       b       c
d       e       f
g       h       i
```

So I need a way to for say

```
Update exampleTableName 
Set Col1 = 'j', Col2 = 'k', Col3 = 'l'
Where rowNumber = 2
```

I am writing this in c++ and using sqlite3, but just the Query should do for me.

Thanks

Edit:

I know this sounds ridiculous and many will ask why the table is set up this way but I am not in control of that. All I can say is that I am able to figure out a row number and need to update each columns value according to what is stored in another variable. Normally these variables will hold the value I want to look up, but it isn't ever guaranteed. So I can only recall the row they want and store it at the time of the look up and then update (the last selected row) by keeping track up its index and updating its values according to w/e is in those variables, which could be the same or could have changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, every row in SQLite has a special column, usually called the "rowid", that uniquely identifies that row within the table. You can use that to select your row.

However if the phrase "WITHOUT ROWID" is added to the end of a CREATE TABLE statement, then the special "rowid" column is omitted. There are sometimes space and performance advantages to omitting the rowid.

```
Update exampleTableName Set Col1 = 'j', Col2 = 'k', Col3 = 'l'   Where rowid= 2
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Much easier than I thought it would be! Would arrow up if I could.

Answer (score 0):

your table needs some form of a primary key...  at a minimum you should add a column named Key INT IDENTITY(1,1) this will give each row a number.

Comment: for example, your table:  CREATE TABLE TableName( Key INT IDENTITY(1,1)  Col1 VARCHAR(5)  Col2 VARCHAR(5) )  and so on...

Comment: O I know that the table is formatted terribly. I cant control that but I am responsible for writing something that will update an entire rows values according to what is stored in some variables. I have a way of knowing which row in the table needs to be edited but have no way of knowing which row by a value because they could have changed them between the recalling of a row and updating. So I only know the row number :/

Comment: can't add a unique key... well then you must be able to identify a unique row somehow, if you have to do a WHERE col1 = 'val1' AND col2= 'val2' etc... you must identify a unique row somehow, otherwise you may actually update more than 1 row...

Comment: Yes I will know the row number if they were indexed by say an imaginary column. Like if values a,b,c are in row 1, d,e,f in row 2 and so on... They "recall" a row or select a row with command. So as I go down the rows looking for w/e value they want. When I find it i keep an index of that row. Then they can do any number of things between the update command. Which includes changing the variables that are used to update a rows values. So to update the row they recall a row. Change the specific variable they want. Then call an update row which uses the last indexed row and just updates each

Comment: value according to the value stored in these "variables"